# Spherical average of a product of two vector lengths

Tags: definite-integrals, vectors, spherical-coordinates, spherical-harmonics

Let $\vec r_1$, $\vec r_2$, and $\vec r$ be vectors in the Cartesian space.

The spherical average $\int |\vec r_1 -\vec r| \, d\Omega$ (where $\Omega$ refers to $\vec r$) readily evaluates to $\frac{2\pi}{3 r_1 r} \,[(r_1+r)^3-|r_1-r|^3]$.

Is there a closed-form expression for $\int |\vec r_1 -\vec r| |\vec r_2 -\vec r| \, d\Omega$ in the general case of $\vec r_1$ not being collinear with $\vec r_2$?

Comment: What is "the Cartesian space"?

Comment: Euclidean space described by Cartesian coordinates

Comment: There are lots of those. Do you mean the three-dimensional one?

Comment: Yes, the 3D one.